# call to sapply() works in interactive mode, not in batch mode

Tags: r

I need to execute some commands in batch mode (e.g., via Rscript).  They work in interactive mode, but not in batch mode.  Here is a minimal example: `sapply(1:3, is, "numeric")`.  Why does this work in interactive mode but return an error in batch mode?  Is there a way to make a command like this work in batch mode?

More specifically, I need to write scripts and to run them in batch mode.  They need to call a function (which I didn't write and can't edit) that looks like this:

```
testfun <- function (...)
{
  args <- list(...)
  if (any(!sapply(args, is, "numeric")))
    stop("All arguments must be numeric.")
  else
    writeLines("All arguments look OK.")
}
```

I need to pass a list to this function.  A command like `testfun(list(1, 2, 3))` works in interactive mode.  But in batch mode, it produces an error: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'is' not found`.  I tried `debugger()` to get a handle on the problem, but it didn't give me any insight.  I also looked through r-help, the R FAQ, R Inferno, but I couldn't find anything that spoke to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rscript doesn't load the methods package by default because it takes a lot of time.  From the *Details* section of `?Rscript`:

```
 ‘--default-packages=list’ where ‘list’ is a comma-separated list
      of package names or ‘NULL’.  Sets the environment variable
      ‘R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES’ which determines the packages loaded on
      startup.  The default for ‘Rscript’ omits ‘methods’ as it
      takes about 60% of the startup time.
```

You can make it load methods by using the `--default-packages` argument.

```
> Rscript -e 'sapply(1:3, is, "numeric")' --default-packages='methods'
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```